# Linq query WHERE one field is >= another field in parent table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How can I translate this:

```
SELECT ExchangeTypes.*, Fixtures.*
FROM Fixtures 
INNER JOIN ExchangeTypes ON Fixtures.ExchangeTypeId = ExchangeTypes.Id 
WHERE ExchangeTypes.LayOdds <= Fixtures.BackOdds
```

into Linq - here's my basic query:

```
        {
        var fixtureDtos = _context.Fixtures   //.Where(c => c.BackOdds >= c.ExchangeType.LayOdds) 
            .Include(c => c.ExchangeType)
            .ToList()
            .Select(Mapper.Map<Fixture, FixtureDto>);

        return Ok(fixtureDtos);
        }
```

Notice there is already a navigation property set up between Fixture and Exchange type (Many to 1).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you use the navigation property (the commented `Where` in your query) which is the preferred way in EF rather than manual joins as in the answer you have accepted?

Comment: In truth I did Ivan do that. I accepted the answer because it enabled me to implement what I wanted but I then realised the reason why my own query was not working was because of a simple data field type mismatch which I corrected and the navigation property worked fine.

I am just new to this and really green.

The answer demonstrates another way of implementing the WHERE that I learnt and others also might find useful.

Comment: Ok, that' explains why you accepted the answer. But I think you should have posted your own answer explaining what you just wrote, because the answer is in fact **not useful** for others because people should learn to use navigation properties and forget about `join`s when working with EF. From the other side, if the question was just how to use `join`s in general LINQ, then it will be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Ok I will do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fixtureDtos = (from m in _context.Fixtures
                  join n in _context.ExchangeTypes
                  on m.ExchangeTypeId = n.Id
                  where n.BackOdds > m.BackOdds
                  select new {/*add columns needed from m and n here*/}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it within EF navigation properties. I was on the right lines in my commented code but had forgotten to ensure that the two field being compared were of the same type (after changing one along the way for testing purposes).

Here's the navigation property linq code:

```
        {
        var fixtureDtos = _context.Fixtures.Where(c => c.BackOdds >= c.ExchangeType.LayOdds)  
            .Include(c => c.ExchangeType)
            .ToList()
            .Select(Mapper.Map<Fixture, FixtureDto>);

        return Ok(fixtureDtos);
    }
```